# Problema en sentencia do while - C++ Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

tengo un pequeño problema con el IDE de Netbeans (o al menos eso creo), ya que ejecuto el programa y se me cicla en el do while cuando no debería ser así, ya lo intente con otros editores con la misma sintaxis, incluso en java y no tengo ningún problema, al parecer es con C++.

Cabe mencionar que no me deja ingresar el número que me pide que ingrese, solamente se cicla instantaneamente en el do while.

Les dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero;

    do{
        cout<<"Ingrese un dígito [1-10] = "<<endl;
        cin>>numero;
    }while(numero<1 || numero>10);  //<---SI SE CUMPLE LA CONDICION SE REPITE, SINO SE SALE

    cout<<"Tabla de multiplicar de "<<numero<<endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <=20; i++) {
        cout<<numero<<" x "<< i<<" = "<<numero*i<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna solución a esto (según yo, algun bug), o ¿quiza tengo algun error en mi código?

Resultado de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al momento de declararlo asignale a la variable número un valor adecuado para que entre al bucle

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado ya lo inicialice con varios valores, y aun asi me sigue tirando el error, (a menos que le ponga entre 1 y 10, ahi me salta directamente el resultado pero no debe ser asi).

Answer (score 1):

no sé si estaré hablando un disparate... Pero intenta no ponerle el  <<endl, pienso que tal vez el cin recibe el salto de línea con ese compilador, y por eso el bug. Pruébalo y dime si te sirvió, por favor

Comment: Favor de leer [answer]

Comment: En vez de usar el término disparate, edita y argumenta el por qué, pues por el contenido con el que respondiste por eso los votos negativos

Comment: Está todo bien explicado, mi estimado, solo tienes que leer bien :)

Comment: Edítala por favor y dale formato al código pues es muy seguro que por eso no se ve el resto de tu aporte, lo que es código selecciónalo y da click en {}

Comment: Ah, vale, lo siento, es que soy nuevo en esto, y no sé usarlo

Comment: @André Ya lo hice, hace lo mismo pero mas "desordenado", se sigue haciendo ese bucle solo que sin el salto de linea, por cierto probé ese mismo código en Netbeans de windows y me sale todo correcto, no se a que se deba que lo haga en ubuntu :/ pero igual me gustaría resolver ese problema

Answer (score 0):

yo e executado el codigo con el compilador g++ y funciona bien

```
Ingrese un dígito [1-10] = 
1
Tabla de multiplicar de 1
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
1 x 3 = 3
1 x 4 = 4
1 x 5 = 5
1 x 6 = 6
1 x 7 = 7
1 x 8 = 8
1 x 9 = 9
1 x 10 = 10
1 x 11 = 11
1 x 12 = 12
1 x 13 = 13
1 x 14 = 14
1 x 15 = 15
1 x 16 = 16
1 x 17 = 17
1 x 18 = 18
1 x 19 = 19
1 x 20 = 20
```

Deverias probar con otro compilador.

Comment: si jaja, en otros compiladores si me funciona, no se que pasa